# C++ Resetting Constructor Values

Tags: c++, loops, constructor, reset, do-while

I had a do loop in my program and I needed to reset the values (from constructor) each time the loop happens until the user exits the program. My Question was: How to make a function to reset values (een, old) as each time loop happens?

I have provided the answer below and with the explanation at the end of the page by answering my own question.

```
class NNew
{
private: 
    int een, old;
public:
    NNew(int nn,int oo)
    {
        een = nn;
        old = oo;
    }
    void newer(int n)
    {
        een = n;
    }
    void Older(int o)
    {
        old = o;
    }
    void reset()
    {
        een = 0;
        old = 0;
    }
};
int main()
{
    char answer1, answer2;
    int n,o;
    NNew *object = new NNew(10,100)
    do
    {
        cout << "Would you like to continue?" << endl;
        cin >> answer1
        if (answer = 'yes')
        {
            do
            {
                (program asks user for inputs for n and o...)
            } while(answer2 !='q');
        }
        object->reset();
    } while(answer1 !='no');
    delete object;
    object = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` is a keyword in C++. It cannot be used as a regular identifier.

Comment: Do you know the answer to my question? tnx

Comment: just add a setter function for `new` and `old`...since you promt the user for new values anyways. And choose variable names that will actually compile.

Comment: While your at it, perhaps heed the compiler warnings you're receiving about `'yes'` and `'no'` not doing what you think they do. And comparisons in C/C++ aren't done with `=`; that is the *assignment* operator.

Comment: @RedAlert, Can you show me how to do that by using only the reset function?

Comment: Your `reset` function seems reasonable. Can you explain why you think it's not working (i.e. show us the actual output and expected output)?

Comment: @AndrewMedico The program runs fine, but it doesn't reset the values for een and old!

Comment: @AndrewMedico, Actual output: For the second loop, program shows the user's entered inputs from the first loop. Expected output: for the first loop, program brings back the values that user has entered. The second loop should bring back new values (different from the first loop's values).

Comment: It would help if you could expand your code to be executable and demonstrate the problem. The cause may lie in the lines you have omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have, a new NNew object is create with every iteration of the loop, if you want to keep the same object with every iteration you can try creating the NNew object before the do...while loop.

FYI whenever you create an object on the heap i.e. with the new keyword, you should delete it when you're done with it.

Comment: Probably not actually the issue - note that there's an inner `do` loop in addition to the outer one.

Comment: @jonvw Thanks, I tried both of your suggestions, but the program still doesn't reset the values!

Comment: @jonvw Thank you, your answer helped me to think differently :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fresh object on each iteration of the loop, you can just use an automatic variable and let the language deal with constructing and destructing it, instead of worrying about manually resetting it:

```
do
{
    NNew object(10,100);

    ...
} while (...);
```

Or if it must be on the heap:

```
do
{
    NNew* object = new NNew(10,100);

    ...

    delete object;
} while (...);
```

Comment: I know how to do it that way. But, I'm experimenting with construct and I'm trying to find out how to use a function to reset the values in the initial constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone that contributed to find the solution.

My question has the answer in itself. I found out the main reason that my code wasn't working was because of some basic issues outside of the example code.

**The example code that I have provided in the question actually works and you can reset constructor values with it.**